# Method '*' has a name conflict with automatic generated getter/setter methods for attribute '*' in class '*'. Please use a different method name

Tags: umple

I have the following Umple model

```
class SomeClass{
  att1;

  Boolean setAtt1(String aAtt1){
    //Do something
  }

}
```

I need to override the setter method of att1. When I try to do it as in the model above, I get a warning. What is the appropriate way to extend setter or getter methods in such a case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setter and getter methods are auto generated, and should not be redefined. Alternatively, what you can do is to use the aspect-orientation features to add before or after as below

```
class SomeClass{
  att1;

  before setAtt1{
    //Do something before
  }

  after setAtt1{
    //Do something after
  }

}
```